# ¿Cómo puedo saber qué es lo que retorna una función en node.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, git, git-clone

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el que usamos la libreria simple-git para ejecutar algunas funcionalidades de Git desde los directorios de javascript. Hay una funcionalidad en especifico que sirve para clonar un repositorio:

```
git.clone(repoPath, localPath, { '--branch': 'develop', '--depth': '1' })
```

Me ha funcionado perfectamente porque clona el repositorio en la ruta loca que le indico. Mi dificultad es que al momento de realizar las pruebas unitarias (con Jest) no tengo muy claro que es lo que retorna esta función. Lo que dice la documentación al respecto es:

***Using task promises**
Each task in the API returns the simpleGit instance for chaining together multiple tasks, and each step in the chain is also a Promise that can be await ed in an async function or returned in a Promise chain.
**Task Responses**
Whether using a trailing callback or a Promise, tasks either return the raw string or Buffer response from the git binary, or where possible a parsed interpretation of the response.
For type details of the response for each of the tasks, please see the TypeScript definitions.*

En visual estudio, cuando pongo el cursor sobre la función me dice que la respuesta es de tipo string, pero al momento de ejecutar las pruebas con Jest, me indica que esta función retornó: {}

Dejo el enlace de la librería por si es de ayuda: https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git

¿Cómo puedo saber qué es lo que retorna esta función?
Les agradezco mucho la ayuda

Comment: lo que debe estar sucediendo es que al ser asincrona estes imprimiendo la respuesta antes de recibirla, por eso en la definicion en ingles te dice que podes usar una await en una funcion asincrona para retornar el resultado o con promesas( .then(...))

Comment: Realemente la estoy utilizando de esta manera, con el async y el await y me sigue apareciendo lo mismo en return.                                                     export async function clone(repoPath: string, localPath: string) {
    return await git.clone(repoPath, localPath, { '--branch': 'develop', '--depth': '1' })
};